# rails nested attributes has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, simple-form

I have three models.  Parent, Child, Type, and Relationship.  Relationship is the rich join model referencing the Parent, Child, and Type.

The problem is that while a child is created and the relationships table is created, the parent_id in the relationships table is not populated.  Only the child and type is is automatically populated.

parent.rb

```
attr_acccessible :relationships_attributes

has_many :relationships
has_many :children, :through => :relationships
has_many :types, :through => :relationships
```

child.rb

```
attr_acccessible :relationships_attributes

has_many :relationships
has_many :parents, :through => :relationships
has_many :types, :through => :relationships

accepts_nested_attributes_for :relationships
```

relationship.rb

```
attr_accessible :parent_id, :child_id, :type_id
belongs_to :parent
belongs_to :child
belongs_to :type
```

children.controller

```
def new
 @child = Child.new
 @child.relationships.build
end

def create
 @child = Child.new(params[:child])
 if @child.save
  redirect_to current_user
 else
  render "new"
 end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @child do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :first_name, :label => 'First Name' %>
  <%= f.input :gender, :as => :select, :collection => ['Male', 'Female'] %>
  <%= f.association :relation_types, :as => :collection_select %>


  <%= f.button :submit, :class => "primary" %>

<% end %>
```

Please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

it seems you forget many things :

```
@child.relationships.build
```

it should be

```
@child.relationships.build :parent_id => ...
```

and in view
instead

```
f.association :relation_types, :as => :collection_select
```

use

```
f.field_for :relationships do |g|
  g.association :types, :as => :collection_select
  g.hidden :parent_id #need to save this
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Is there another way to incorporate the parent ID?  I rather not use hidden fields.

Comment: if you dont want it in parent id maybe you can hide it in params (changing form url or changing routes.rb make this resource nested(this is not easy))

Comment: You can also use `@child = @parent.children.build`